# How to iterate over matrix in NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have googled it quite a lot and didn't find anything. I have a simple question, how can I iterate over a matrix in Python? I am talking about `numpy.matrix` and not `numpy.array`.

Edit: 
I want to run function:

```
def activation(X):
    print ('X: ', X)
    ret = np.zeros(len(X))
    i = 0
    for x in X:
        i = i + 1
        ret[i] = (1 / (1 + math.exp(-x))) 

    return ret
```

Comment: Which parts of the documentation are you having trouble with?

Comment: Run means. What you expect as output ? a matrix ?

Comment: I want to use this function: 
def activation(X):
    print ('X: ', X)
    ret = np.zeros(len(X))
    i = 0
    for x in X:
        print ('x: ', x)
        i = i + 1
        ret[i] = (1 / (1 + math.exp(-x))) 
        
    return ret

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do the following:

```
mat = np.matrix([[1,2],[3,4]])
ret = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-mat))
```

Your whole function will then be:

```
def activation(X):
    print("X: ", X)
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-X))
```

Note: This will also return a `np.matrix` with the same shape as `X`

If you are using Scipy, then `expit` from [`scipy.special`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.special.expit.html) does exactly this.